# Removing the smaller sets of values from an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array that consists of arrays containing integers.

```
[[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

What would be the preferred way in Swift to remove the arrays that contains a smaller number of elements with a certain value and keep only the larger arrays containing that value.

The result from the input above would be

```
[[5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Do you want this to be stable (preserving the original order), what should be done about duplicates? I assume you only want arrays left over with the highest count.

Comment: The order does not matter, I have edited my question to make it more clear. Yes only the arrays with the highest count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `[Int: [Int]]` dictionary to keep track of the largest array for the value specified by the key.

```
let arrays = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
var largest = [Int: [Int]]()

for arr in arrays {
    // Get the first value from the array
    if let first = arr.first {

        // current is the count for that key already in dictionary largest
        // If the key isn't found, the nil coalescing operator ?? will
        // return the default count of 0.
        let current = largest[first]?.count ?? 0

        // If our new array has a larger count, put it in the dictionary
        if arr.count > current {
            largest[first] = arr
        }
    }
}

// Convert the dictionary's values to an array for the final answer.   
let result = Array(largest.values)

print(result)  // [[5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

---

This same logic can be used with `reduce` to provide the result in one line:

```
let result = arrays.reduce([Int: [Int]]()) { var d = $0; guard let f = $1.first else { return d }; d[f] = d[f]?.count > $1.count ? d[f] : $1; return d }.map { $1 }
```

---

**Alternate Version**

This version uses a `[Int: Int]` dictionary to just keep the counts of the largest array found for each key, and then reconstructs the arrays at the end using an array constructor.

```
let arrays = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
var counts = [Int: Int]()

for arr in arrays {
    if let first = arr.first {
        counts[first] = max(counts[first] ?? 0, arr.count)
    }
}

let result = counts.map { [Int](count: $1, repeatedValue: $0) }

print(result)  // [[5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

---

This same logic can be used with `reduce` to provide the result in one line:

```
let result = arrays.reduce([Int: Int]()) { var d = $0; guard let f = $1.first else { return d }; d[f] = max(d[f] ?? 0, $1.count); return d }.map { [Int](count: $1, repeatedValue: $0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to write up my answer when I saw that vacawama had responded with something very similar. Decided to come back to it though just because it's an interesting problem to play around with. So my alternative is almost certainly much slower that vacawama's solutions and doesn't preserve the order, but I thought it was interesting as an example of the alternatives that you have for solving problems like this in Swift.

```
var items = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]

let reduced = items.sort({
        let lhs = $0.first, rhs = $1.first
        return lhs == rhs ? $0.count > $1.count : lhs < rhs
    }).reduce( [[Int]]()) { (res, items) in
        return res.last?.last != items.last ? res + [items] : res
    }

print(reduced)  // [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7]]
```

Or if you'd rather cram all that on a single line:

```
var items = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]

let reduced = items.sort({ let lhs = $0.first, rhs = $1.first; return lhs == rhs ? $0.count > $1.count : lhs < rhs }).reduce([[Int]]()) { $0.last?.last != $1.last ? $0 + [$1] : $0 }

print(reduced)  // [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative using forEach:

```
let arrays = [[2],  [2, 2], [5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [3]]
var largest: [Int: [Int]] = [:]

arrays.forEach({
    guard let first = $0.first else { return }
    largest[first] = [Int](count: max($0.count,largest[first]?.count ?? 0), repeatedValue: first)
})
Array(largest.values)  // [[5], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```